# The qr code scanner I wrote with javascript does not work on my phone

Tags: javascript, qr-code

hi everyone i am trying to make a qr code scanner running the code on my localhost but when i connect to localhost from the phone i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.btnScanQR.onclick" can you help me?

First page is my javascript
Second page is my html

```js
const qrcodes = window.qrcodes;

const video = document.createElement("video");
const canvasElement = document.getElementById("qr-canvas");
const canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

const qrResult = document.getElementById("qr-result");
const outputData = document.getElementById("outputData");
const btnScanQR = document.getElementById("btn-scan-qr");

let scanning = false;

qrcode.callback = res => {
  if (res) {
    outputData.innerText = res;
    scanning = false;

    video.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });

    qrResult.hidden = false;
    canvasElement.hidden = true;
    btnScanQR.hidden = false;
  }
};

btnScanQR.onclick = () => {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } })
    .then(function(stream) {
      scanning = true;
      qrResult.hidden = true;
      btnScanQR.hidden = true;
      canvasElement.hidden = false;
      video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.play();
      tick();
      scan();
    });
};

function tick() {
  canvasElement.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvasElement.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  scanning && requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

function scan() {
  try {
    qrcode.decode();
  } catch (e) {
    setTimeout(scan, 300);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Qr Code Scanner</title>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/sitepoint-editors/jsqrcode/master/src/qr_packed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>BTC QR Code Scanner</h1>

        <input type="button" id="btn-scan-qr" value="Scan">

        <canvas id="qr-canvas"></canvas>

        <div id="qr-result" hidden="">
            <b>Result:</b> <span id="outputData"></span>
        </div>

        <script src="qrCodeScanner.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that your device’s browser doesn't support this API yet.

Comment: but on other sites my camera works but localhost also doesn't work